# Oracle Database: Index-Organized Table with NULL Values (in Multiple-Column Primary Key)

Tags: database, oracle, null, indexing, primary-key

How can I set a column to be an "" (the empty string, equivalent to NULL in Oracle), when that column is part of a multiple-column primary key? This is the motivation...

```
CREATE TABLE entities (
  column1  VARCHAR2(10)
, column2  VARCHAR2(10)
, body     VARCHAR2(4000)
, CONSTRAINT pk_entities            -- can't do this, because sometimes
  PRIMARY KEY ( column1, column2 )  -- col2 is the empty string (NULL).
) ORGANIZATION INDEX ...
```

Normally, I'd use a "real" primary key like a meaningless sequential id (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423507/how-to-have-a-primary-key-with-null-values-using-empty-string)) and then put a unique constraint over my data columns, like so...

```
CREATE TABLE entities (
, id       NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
, column1  VARCHAR2(10)
, column2  VARCHAR2(10)
, body     VARCHAR2(4000)
, CONSTRAINT unq_entities 
  UNIQUE ( column1, column2 )
) ORGANIZATION INDEX ...
```

However, this is a big index-organized table (IOT), so the primary key *has* to be on the data columns (in IOTs, the data is the index) or else... What should I do?

Thanks! ♥

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a "feature" peculiar to Oracle. Unlike other SQL DBMSs it doesn't support the zero-length string value and insists on converting it to a null.

You could create another column as a flag to represent the zero-length string and then store spaces in place of the column itself. I don't think there is a perfect workaround though. It's a little surprising that Oracle hasn't fixed this odd limitation - especially given the enormous improvements they've made in other ways to comply with the SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

replace the empty string with a dummy string and check for it later... depends how the table is bieng used though.

Comment: Can't do this; the value in `column2` can be *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you *need* the table to be an IOT? a UNIQUE INDEX on column1,column2 with a heap table will probably be nearly as efficient for data retrieval.

IOTs (similar to a table with a clustered index) are the exception, not the norm in Oracle.